# Multi-variable List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am working on [Project Euler #35](http://projecteuler.net/problem=35), and I need to find the circular permutations of a number. Using `itertools`, I can easily get the permutations of a number. However, I want to do it with a list comprehension (as it seems more Pythonic; I am also trying to get familiar with list comprehensions).

I found that all circular primes can only contain the digits 1, 3, 7, and 9 (this excludes 2 and 5, which are circular primes by definition). If any other digit was in the number (0, 2, 4, 5, 6, or 8) one of the permutations would not be a prime (as that digit would be last in at least one of the permutations).

Thus, I tried doing this:

```
from itertools import permutations
l = [x for x in list(permutations('1397', y)) for y in range(7)]
```

I needed to use `y for y in range(7)` so that I get varying lengths of permutations.

However, this gave me a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    l = [x for x in list(permutations('1397', y)) for y in range(7)]
TypeError: an integer is required
```

This works, but it isn't using two variables in one list comprehension:

```
l = []
for y in range(7):
    l.append([x for x in list(permutations('1379', y))])
```

How can I do a double-variable list comprehension? Thanks!

Comment: Tip: nested list comprehensions have the same `for` order as nested loops.  `for y in range(7): for x in permutations('1397', y): newlist.append(x)` becomes `newlist = [x for y in range(7) for x in permutations('1397', y)]`.

Comment: `list(permutations('1379', y))` is already a list, the for-loop:
`[x for x in list(permutations('1379', y))]` is useless.

Comment: You should not be using itertools.permitations at all. The problem is to find circular permutations, which is a special kind of permutation. It is much easier to generate them directly without itertools.permutation (you will need to filter results otherwise). Also using special python Standard library functions is not appropriate for exercises like the one you are trying to solve

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `for y in range(7)` part should come before the permutation loop.:

```
l = [x for y in range(7) for x in list(permutations('1397', y))]
```

The above list comprehension is equivalent to :

```
In [93]: l = []

In [94]: for y in range(7):
    ...:     l.extend(list(permutations('1397', y)))
```

For example:

```
In [76]: l = [x for y in range(3) for x in list(permutations('1397', y))]

In [77]: l
Out[77]: 
[(),
 ('1',),
 ('3',),
 ('9',),
 ('7',),
 ('1', '3'),
 ('1', '9'),
 ('1', '7'),
 ('3', '1'),
 ('3', '9'),
 ('3', '7'),
 ('9', '1'),
 ('9', '3'),
 ('9', '7'),
 ('7', '1'),
 ('7', '3'),
 ('7', '9')]
```

And the `list-comprehension` version for your working example,

```
l = []
for y in range(7):
    l.append(list(permutations('1397', y)))
```

is:

```
In [85]: l = [list(permutations('1397', y)) for y in range(3)]

In [86]: l
Out[86]: 
[[()],
 [('1',), ('3',), ('9',), ('7',)],
 [('1', '3'),
  ('1', '9'),
  ('1', '7'),
  ('3', '1'),
  ('3', '9'),
  ('3', '7'),
  ('9', '1'),
  ('9', '3'),
  ('9', '7'),
  ('7', '1'),
  ('7', '3'),
  ('7', '9')]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[list(permutations('1397',x)) for x in range(7)]
```

Comment: This result is only the same since the original question has `[x for x in ...]`. The way I see it, the idea is that there is a nested list comprehension, which would allow for something like `[x*x for x in ...]`, which is not possible with this answer. Perhaps you could simply introduce your answer with something along the lines of "don't use a nested list comprehension, just use this:".